# выбрать из таблицы одинаковые множества

Tags: sql

Есть таблица отправки сообщений M отправителя S одному или нескольким получателям R, например:

```
M | S | R
--+---+--
1 | 1 | 2
2 | 1 | 1
2 | 1 | 2
3 | 2 | 1
4 | 2 | 1
4 | 2 | 2
```

Со временем оказалось, что группы получателей сообщений чаще одни и те же, стало быть лучше выделить их в отдельную таблицу и каждое сообщение M связывать с одной единственной группой получателей G:

```
M | G
--+---
1 | 1 == R:{2}
2 | 2 == R:{1, 2}
3 | 3 == R:{1}
4 | 2 == R:{1, 2}
```

то есть

```
G | R
--+---
1 | 2
2 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 1
```

Вопрос: возможно ли средствами SQL преобразовать первую таблицу в последнюю, т.е. сгруппировать множества получателей R сообщений в одну таблицу исключив повторы (в примере сообщения 2 и 4 были отправлены одной и той же группе получателей {1, 2} ) ?

Comment: Какой диалект SQL и сколько сейчас пользователей в БД (максимальный ID)

Answer (score 2):

Вы не указали диалект SQL на котором это надо сделать. В разных диалектах есть разные подходы для решения этой задачи, которые будут гораздо эффективнее приводимого ниже боле менее универсального решения.

```
select distinct G, R
  from 
   (
    select min(M1) G from
       (
        select M1.M M1,M2.M M2
          from mess M1, mess M2,
               (select M, count(1) cnt,sum(R) rs
                  from mess group by M) C1,
               (select M, count(1) cnt,sum(R) rs
                  from mess group by M) C2
         where M1.R=M2.R
           and C1.M=M1.M and C2.M=M2.M
           and C1.cnt=C2.cnt and C1.rs=C2.rs
         group by M1.M,M2.M
        having count(1)=max(C1.cnt)
      ) A
    group by M2
  ) Z, mess M
 where M.M=Z.G
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dfefb/1)

ID групп назначаются не подряд, а по ID минимального сообщения с такой группой. Если взять содержимое подзапроса `Z` и помимо G вывести M2 - то получим список сообщений с ID групп получателей, что скорее всего потребуется что бы вставить в какую нибудь еще таблицу.

Логика запроса: Для каждого сообщения получаем количество получателей и сумму ID получателей. Переклеиваем таблицу сообщений саму с собой и полученными количествами по условию равенства получателей и количеств/сумм. Если количество таких записей в разрезе одного и любого другого сообщений совпадает с общим количеством получателей сообщения - то такие сообщения имеют одинаковый набор получателей. Минимальный ID сообщения 1 из пар равных между собой в разрезе ID сообщения 2 и есть набор необходимых групп, правда в результате запроса одна и та же группа повторяется много раз, но ID взят минимальный, так что он одинаков для всех одинаковых сообщений. Остается доклеить к нему таблицу сообщений, взять уникальные записи и вот мы получили требуемый результат. Суммы ID получателей (`rs`) особо не нужны, они служат для некоторой оптимизации выборки, отсеивая часть наборов с одинаковым количеством.

P.S. Написано в MySQL в котором, как и в Oracle, MS SQL, Postgress можно вместо обычного JOIN писать оператор "запятая" и выносить условия объединения в from. Если Ваша СУБД не поддерживает этого оператора или он не равноценен JOIN то придется заменить запятые на JOIN и перенести условия объединения в конструкции ON.

Comment: Большое спасибо за столь подробный ответ, на его основе удалось конвертировать рабочую БД.
В моём случае тоже использовался MySQL, но оптимизация запросов не так важна поскольку речь идет об одноразовом изменении структуры.