# Выборка MySql (многие ко многим)

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такая таблица:
[image: Таблица]

Как видно? у Иванова и Сидорова идентичный набор учеников. Как вытащить из таблицы Иванова и Сидорова? Или как вытащить данные учителей с одинаковым набором учеников?

Comment: Уточните входные данные, задан ли набор учеников, или может задан учитель и нужно найти других учителей с таким же набором учеников. Я к тому, что кроме Иванова и Сидорова с одинаковыми наборами учеником могут быть, например, Андреев и Алексеев, у которых одинаковый набор учеников друг с другом, но отличный от набора учеников Иванова и Сидорова

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526470/

Comment: @Андрей в данном случае задан набор учеников. Выбрать всех учителей с заданным набором учеников.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиск всех учителей у которых строго заданный набор учеников:

```
SELECT teacher_id 
  FROM `teacher_student` a
 GROUP BY teacher_id
HAVING count(1)=4 and sum(student_id IN (10,7,9,8))=4
```

Поиск учителей у которых есть как минимум данные ученики, но, возможно, не только они:

```
SELECT teacher_id 
  FROM `teacher_student` a
 WHERE student_id IN (10,7,9,8)
 GROUP BY teacher_id
HAVING count(1)=4
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш вариант намного элегантнее. Но кажется во втором коде небольшая опечатка в HAVING, а именно '=' вместо '>'

Comment: @phpХ Там не может быть больше 4, потому что перед выполнением group by и having будет выбрано не более 4х записей, по условию в where

Comment: странно :), но когда я ставлю '>' то я получаю то что хочу, а именно, учителя у которого как минимум данный набор учеников

Comment: @phpХ тогда выполните первые 3 строки, до group by и посмотрите по какому из учителей сколько записей найдено и найдите те где это число больше 4х. этого не может быть, если конечно у вас у какого то из учителей не дублируется один и тот же ученик более 1 раза

Comment: Да. Все верно, так как вы сказали. Перепроверил.Но тогда второй запрос мне не понадобится. Потому что во втором случае мне нужны только учителя у которых как мин. данный набор учеников.

Comment: Для второго случае вполне сгодился ваш первый код, как раз там и поставил '>' в `HAVING count(1)=4` Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В чем проблема, просто делаем запрос:

```
SELECT teacher_id FROM your_table WHERE student_id='$1' AND student_id='$2' ... AND student_id='$n';
```

Условия WHERE надо будет сформировать программно в зависимости от того, какой вы используете язык программирования. Например, для PHP будет такой код:

```
$where = array();
foreach ($students as $a) $where[] = "student_id='".$a."'";
$where = implode(" AND ", $where);
```

где `$students` набор id учеников, а `$where` - наши условия поиска.

P.S. Также настоятельно рекомендую назначить на колонку student_id индекс.

Comment: Вроде прекрасное решение, но не работает такой запрос. Возвращает пустой результат.

Comment: @phpХ вы проверьте какой запрос у вас в итоге получается с вашими данными. далее попробуйте его выполнить отдельно (например, в phpmyadmin). если также ничего не вернет, то дело уже не в запросе.

Comment: Да, я проверил. Никак не хочет выдавать результат. Но решение уже найдено. Можете посмотреть другие ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел отличное решение

```
SELECT teacher_id 
FROM   `teacher_student` a
WHERE  student_id IN (10,7,9,8) AND
        EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    `teacher_student` b
            WHERE   a.teacher_id = b.teacher_id
            GROUP   BY teacher_id
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) = 4
        )
GROUP  BY teacher_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461707/mysql-only-in-equivalent-clause

Работает.

А как интересно можно сделать выборку учителей у который данный на вход набор учеников В ТОМ ЧИСЛЕ среди его учеников?