# SQL Подсчет уникальных значений и исключение определенных

Tags: sql, условия

Есть таблица `event`:

```
(id_user)  (status)
1      active
2      load
3      active
1      load
2      active
3      active
1      active
3      fail
```

Для каждого `id_user` необходимо вывести количество строк этого `id_user`, проходящих по условию `(status="active" OR status="load") AND (status!="fail")`. Результат примерно такой:

```
(id_user)  count(status)
1      3
2      2
```

`id_user = 3` не попал, потому что у него была одна строка `status!="fail"`.

Если такой запрос оформить возможно, сразу второй вопрос, если нужно исключить те `id_user`, у которых больше двух строк `status!="fail"`?

Comment: Какой именно SQL у вас ? Вот давеча для MySQL попадалось https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688427/  такими же count с условиями ваши задачи так же должны решится ...

Comment: ‍‍
‌‌‍‍
‌‌‍‍
‌‌‍‍
‌‌‍‍
‌‌‍‍
‌‌‍‍
‌‌‍‍
‌‌‍‍
‌‌‍‍
‌‌‍‍
MySQL

Comment: так сделайте по аналогии с тем ответом, `sum(status="active" OR status="load")` и в having проверяйте `sum(status="fail")` на 0 или не более 2

Comment: Для случая `AND (status!="fail")`, поскольку статусов всего 3, и один из них обязан отсутствовать, количество можно считать и обычным COUNT().